# Azure Project Error - Output Type in Project Settings

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I am working on Azure application. After I have updated my Visual Studio 2017 to the latest release, the Azure Function Apps started throwing error while running. Following is the error I am facing -

A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly.

Earlier, the application was running fine. I have tried uninstalling the VS2017 but still no luck. Has anybody faced similar issue? Please note, this is running perfectly on my colleague's machine, not sure why I am facing this error.

Comment: Did you mean if your colleague uses the latest release in vs2017, it works fine on his machine? And what's the version about your azure function?

Comment: No, he is not using latest version. I am afraid if he gets latest version, he might face same problem. Not sure how can I revert back to previous version.

Comment: What about the latest version? Could you show us like screenshot?

Comment: Azure Functions and Web Job Tools - version 15.0.40405.0
Visual Studio 2017 - version 15.6.6

Comment: That's the error I see if my Functions/WebJobs tools are disabled or not installed. Did you validate that they weren't disabled?

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is in a comment by brettsam, so I'll restate it here because I almost missed it:

You don't need to downgrade. You need Azure Functions and Web Jobs installed.

You can get it through the Visual Studio Installer under the "ASP.NET and web development" package. I think it should be under "Cloud tools for web development" but I went ahead and installed both the "ASP.NET and web development" and the "Azure development" packages.

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above issue by downgrading the version of Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions to 1.0.8. Earlier, it was 1.0.9, when I downgraded, it started working fine.

Comment: You don't need to downgrade -- see my answer.